# Use C program inside Fortran

Tags: c, fortran

I have the C program [triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) (free software), from

http://www.netlib.org/voronoi/triangle.zip   (this is the code)

Triangle read a A.poly file (is in that .zip file) and generates other files (A.1.node, A.1.ele and other), running the command line

```
triangle A.poly
```

I need to use triangle (C program) from my fortran code but without using the input file A.poly, and not generating the files A.1.node or A.1.ele.

I want to forgot read input file and write output files, and just use arrays inside fortran. This because I need to use this routine inside of a do loop (for loop) of hundred thousand iterations.

There exists some way to do this?

I'm working on linux, but I don't know if this have relevance.

Comment: .oOo. I will just grab my popcorn and wait paintiently for the magic solution ;) .oOo.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass data from C into a couple of Fortran arrays?

Comment: @mko: mmm, I don't understand your comment, it's a joke? this website is precisely for do question, no? If you know about this topic, would be very useful for me point me how to solve this problem. Obviously, it's not necessary the complete code (someone suggested that?). I just ask for some guidance

Comment: @user10630 It's not about you. I fully understand your issue. In fact I have posted answer that was downwoted. So, now, I am waiting for alternative solutions from downwoters :) In my opinion, without altering the code and making it suitable for fortran-c calls you will not be able to proceed :(

Comment: @MattP I want to use the C program, called triangle, inside of my Fortran rutine. Originally, triangle need the input file "A.poly" and generate two output files: "A.1.node" and "A.1.ele". I need to use this output files. Is this possible?
So, I need to pass data from Fortran to C (the input file A.poly of triangle software), and from C to Fortran (the output of triangle). But I don't want generate the files (read and write files).

Comment: @mko : I understand ;)   So, your suggestion is modify the C program for that their input and output files be just one and two arrays, respectively? In the case of triangle (the C program) only have one array of input and two array of output...   how can I use triangle (the C problem) inside of my Fortran code? How can I find information (or some symple example) in google or in some place?

Comment: So, you want to use Fortran to call a C program, avoid writing any output files and instead pass results directly back to Fortran. This is possible. You should look into Fortran's `ISO_C_BINDING`, which assists with mixed language programming, and you will need to consider whether the data types are interoperable. When you run into a specific programming question and can illustrate it with some code, you'll likely get more positive feedback. There are actually plenty of examples here on SO dealing with Fortran/C programming.

Comment: This is the place you want to check: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html You can find there lots of samples illustrating how to call C from Fortran and vice versa.

Comment: It might also be an option to use some triangulation (?) library already written in Fortran (rather than trying to connect to a C version). For example, searching the net with "triangulate fortran code" gives [GEOMPACK](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/geompack/implement.shtml) , [triangulation](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/triangulation/triangulation.html) , etc, though I have no idea which is good or convenient to use...